# Java 8 nested for loop and conditions

Tags: java, java-8, nested

I am having a bit of trouble reducing this for loop into a stream in Java 8, the output from the stream does not match with the `for` loop

```
for (Object1 ob1s : getObject1s){
            if (ob1s.hasChild != null){
                map1.get(ob1holder).add(ob1s);
                if(Objects.equals(ob1.getHolder, Boolean.TRUE))
                {
                    map1.get(ob11holder).add(ob1s.getID);
                }
                if (ob1s.getObject2 != null){
                for (Object2 ob2 : ob1s.getObject2.getObjects){
                    map.get(ob2holder).add(ob2);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Attempted:

```
getObject1s.stream()
                .filter(ob1s -> ob1s.hasChild != null)
                .map(ob1s ->
                    {map.get(ob1holder).add(ob1s);
                    if (Objects.equals(ob1.getHolder, Boolean.TRUE))
                        { map.get(ob11holder).add(ob1s.getID);}
                    return ob1s;})
                .filter(ob1s -> ob1s.getObject2 != null)
                .flatMap(ob1s -> ob1s.getObject2.getObjects.stream())
                .map(ob2 -> map.get(ob2holder).add(ob2));
```

Comment: Why do you think the stream-based code would be better?

Comment: Not necessarily better, reduces the visible-Cyclic complexity within my code, because I am planning to introduce another nested `for` loop.

Comment: You are abusing the `map` method here. The map function should be stateless and non-interfering; you are changing `map1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner:  Sadly your initial comment isn't all that helpful...since `Stream`s have to have a terminal operation to *do* anything...it doesn't matter what the ideal state is.

Comment: And you should use `Objects.equals(ob1.getHolder, Boolean.TRUE)`, unless you really are trying to compare by identity.

Comment: @AndyTurner that was just a fabricated comparison, assume that statement is logical

Comment: @Makoto the premise of the question is that it is *worth* rewriting with streams; often, the reason to want to use streams is the belief they are going to do something better. This belief is worth challenging, because it is not true. So, y'know, chuck on a terminal operation, and I will still ask the same question.

Comment: "not true" not *universally or automatically* true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no terminal operation in your stream so stream is not executed.

```
getObject1s.stream()
        .filter(ob1s -> ob1s.hasChild != null)
        .forEach(ob1s ->{
            map1.get(ob1holder).add(ob1s);
            if(Boolean.TRUE.equal(ob1.getHolder)){  //null safe
                map1.get(ob11holder).add(ob1s.getID);
            }
            if (ob1s.getObject2 != null){
              ob1s.getObject2.getObjects.stream()
                     .forEach(ob2 -> map.get(ob2holder).add(ob2));
            }
    })
```

Comment: can I not convert the `for` in the second condition into another stream? Oh wait nvm, let me get back to you